# Instagram does not load stories

Tags: iphone, instagram

iPhone 8: Instagram has problems loading stories. The circle appears and it is loading dozens of seconds each video or freezing at loading.

What I have done so far:

1. tested on Wi-Fi
2. tested on cellular data
3. turned on/off assistant (to smart switch between Wi-Fi and cellular data)
4. reinstalled instagram app
5. rebooted phone

Other apps are working ok, the problem exists only in instagram.

EDIT: Seems like from 2020-12-18 the problem is gone on iOS 14.2. I suspect Instagram app update has resolved the problem. iOS 14.3 seems fine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have already tried a lot of things. Do you happen to have iOS 14.1 ? I heard that this problem happens on it. Perhaps one of these methods will help you:

- Clear your Instagram App Cache
- Update your Instagram to the Latest
- Turn Off Power Saving Mode
- Turn off/on airplane mode
- Try to log out/log in

Comment: Seems like the problem is gone, I've edited the question. I will check for iOS 14.3 in a moment, just updating.